# Drupal 7 - 'Text on Image' Conversion

Tags: image, drupal, image-processing, drupal-7, image-conversion

How can we convert the contents of the article into **image/pdf** format in **drupal 7**.

Suppose, we are viewing a article in some textformat (ie default format of drupal) and if we want to see the contents of article on a image format.

I'm dealing with content that is some value and can't be openly published without any security. Though i know its baseless to restrict others from copying the content, but still i like doing my own piece of work to stop content copying.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? When someone requests a page (e.g. mysite.com/node/10) you want to display a PDF version of the node instead of the node itself?

Answer (score 0):

you can also use a module [Cufon](http://drupal.org/project/cufon) for text[1](http://drupal.org/project/cufon) to image conversion